# How to build a dataframe thats a join of two kafka streams with "key(s)" column and remaining columns being the latest values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

My Spark 2.4.x (pyspark) app requires:

1. Inputs are two Kafka topics and output is a Kafka topic
2. A "streaming table" where

   - there's a logical key(s) and
   - remaining columns should be latest values from either stream(s).
3. Sub-second latency. Tests show this is achievable when `watermarks` are not 
   used.

This seems like a basic thing, but its not working completely for me.

---

### Example:

**NOTE**: In example below, T1, T2 & T2 points-in-time could be seconds/minutes/hours apart.

**T1)** At Time **T1**

**KafkaPriceTopic** gets 1 message payload (lets call it ***P1***):
`{ "SecurityCol":"Sec1", "PriceSeqNoCol":"1", "PriceCol": "101.5"}`

**KafkaVolumeTopic** 1 message with payload (lets call it ***V1***):
`{ "SecurityCol":"Sec1", "VolumeSeqNoCol":"1", "VolumeCol": "50"}`

I'd like to have a **Result `DataFrame`** that looks like:

```
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+ 
|SecurityCol|PriceCol|VolumeCol|PriceSeqNoCol|VolumeSeqNoCol|  
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+ 
|Sec1       |101.5   |50       |1            |1             |
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

**T2)**  **KafkaPriceTopic** 1 message (***P2***):
`{ "SecurityCol":"Sec1", "PriceSeqNoCol":"2", "PriceCol": "101.6"}`

**Result `DataFrame`**

```
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+ 
|SecurityCol|PriceCol|VolumeCol|PriceSeqNoCol|VolumeSeqNoCol|  
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+ 
|Sec1       |101.6   |50       |2            |1             |
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

**NOTE**: ***P1*** not relevant anymore

**T3)**  **KafkaVolumeTopic** 1 message ***V2***:
`{ "SecurityCol":"Sec1", "VolumeSeqNoCol":"2", "VolumeCol": "60"}`

**Result `DataFrame`**

```
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+ 
|SecurityCol|PriceCol|VolumeCol|PriceSeqNoCol|VolumeSeqNoCol|
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
|Sec1       |101.6   |60       |2            |2             |
+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

**NOTE**: ***P1*** & ***V1*** not relevant anymore

---

### What Works

1. extract the json from the payload (`get_json_object` for now),
   `join` the two topic's streams.
2. However. this would yield (w/o `watermark`) a `DataFrame` that has all the 
   Price & Volume received for *Sec1* and not just the latest of either.
3. So this is followed by a `groupBy(...).agg(last(...),...)`. But am stuck on 
   just getting one row with the latest value.

```py
    dfKafka1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka"). #remaining options etc
                .load()
                .select(...)                     #pulls out fields as columns" 

    dfKafka2 = spark.readStream.format("kafka"). #remaining options etc
               .load()
               .select(...)                     #pulls out fields as columns" 

    dfResult=dfKafka1.join(dfKafka2,"SecurityCol")

#structured streaming doesnt yet allow groupBy after a join, so write to intermediate kafka topic

   dfResult.writestream.format("kafka"). #remaining options
           .trigger(processingTime="1 second")
           .start()

#load intermediate kafka topic
   dfKafkaResult=spark.readStream.format("kafka"). #remaining options
                 .load()
                 .select(...)                      #get_json_object for cols
                 .groupBy("SecurityCol")           #define the "key" to agg cols
                 .agg(last("PriceCol"),            #most recent value per col
                      last("PriceSeqNoCol"),
                      last("VolumeCol"),
                      last("VolumeSeqNoCol"))
```

---

### Problem

However the final `agg` & `last()` doesn't do the trick consistently.

1. When KafkaVolumeTopic gets a new message, the result might have a join with 
   an older message from KafkaPriceTopic.
2. Further `orderBy`/sort cant be used on a stream w/o an aggregation.

---

### Restrictions

1. I cant `groupBy` before the `join` since that would require `withWatermark`, and i think my app cant use `watermark`. Rationale:

   - The app should be able to join the two topics for a given SecurityCol any time during the day.

     - If PriceTopic gets a message at 9am and VolumeTopic at 10am
     - i'd expect the two to be joined and present
   - A watermark restricts when data is emitted in `append` mode. So cant use watermark here since the timeframe is whole day.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue ? My case is also similar.